# Tried to install airflow 1.10.3 in airflow, but airflow 1.10.5 is installed

Tags: apache-http-server, pip

I am using pip install `apache-airflow[1.10.3]`, but `apache-airflow-1.10.5` is installed.

Log is below, it says `apache-airflow-1.10.5` is installed:

```
Successfully installed Babel-2.7.0 Flask-Babel-0.12.2 Flask-JWT-Extended-3.24.0 Flask-OpenID-1.2.5 Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.4.1 Mako-1.1.0 PyJWT-1.7.1 alembic-1.2.1 apache-airflow-1.10.5 apispec-3.0.0 cached-property-1.5.1 colorama-0.4.1 colorlog-4.0.2 configparser-3.5.3 croniter-0.3.30 defusedxml-0.6.0 dill-0.2.9 docutils-0.15.2 dumb-init-1.2.2 flask-1.1.1 flask-admin-1.5.3 flask-appbuilder-1.13.1 flask-caching-1.3.3 flask-login-0.4.1 flask-swagger-0.2.13 flask-wtf-0.14.2 funcsigs-1.0.0 future-0.16.0 iso8601-0.1.12 json-merge-patch-0.2 jsonschema-3.1.1 lazy-object-proxy-1.4.2 lockfile-0.12.2 markdown-2.6.11 marshmallow-2.19.5 marshmallow-enum-1.5.1 marshmallow-sqlalchemy-0.19.0 numpy-1.17.3 ordereddict-1.1 pandas-0.25.2 pendulum-1.4.4 prison-0.1.0 psutil-5.6.3 pygments-2.4.2 pyrsistent-0.15.4 python-daemon-2.1.2 python-editor-1.0.4 python3-openid-3.1.0 pytz-2019.3 pytzdata-2019.3 setproctitle-1.1.10 sqlalchemy-1.3.10 tabulate-0.8.5 tenacity-4.12.0 termcolor-1.1.0 text-unidecode-1.2 thrift-0.11.0 tzlocal-1.5.1 unicodecsv-0.14.1 wtforms-2.2.1 zope.deprecation-4.4.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`pip` uses [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/#files), which normally only maintains the latest releases of a given module. So you need to obtain older versions of a module elsewhere and install them manually.

**Installing airflow 1.10.3**

- Download and extract [airflow 1.10.3](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/#files) from GitHub.
- Uninstall the current version of `airflow` e.g.:

  ```
  python -m pip uninstall apache-airflow
  ```
- Install the version of airflow from Step 1 using `python -m pip install .` or `python setup.py install`.

Note that in the last step above, the source code you downloaded in Step 1 must be compiled (as there are apparently no pre-compiled `.whl` files available on GitHub for 1.10.3 currently). The suggested steps for compilation (in the last step) are taken from [this official documentation](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/INSTALL).